# Сайты на Docker падают через Nое время без работы

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, docker

Docker развернул несколько сайтов на готовых докер контейнерах с официальных репозиториев.Если долго заходить на сайт он падает (вечная анимация загрузки). Если подключиться в серверу по SSH то контейнер "отвисает" и начинает работать. Такая проблема не с отдельным контейнером, а с пачкой из 3 веб приложений. ОС Ubuntu 18

Comment: Ну а листинг `docker-compose.yml` посмотреть можно?